# I want to filter the NSFW url on discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

This is the code

```
const body = await fetch(`https://shot.screenshotapi.net/screenshot?&url=${encodeURIComponent(args.join(" "))}&fresh=true&output=json&file_type=png&wait_for_event=load`)
           .then(res => res.json().catch(() => { }));

            if (args.length === 0) return message.channel.send({
               embed: {
                    color: config.embedcolor,
                    title: "Please provide a valid URL!"
               }
            })
            if (!body) return message.channel.send({
                embed: {
                    color: config.embedcolor,
                    title: "❌ Error"
                }
            })
            if (body.error) return message.channel.send({
                embed: {
                    color: config.embedcolor,
                    title: "❌ Error URL not found"
                }
            });

            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(` ${body.url} `)
                .setColor(config.embedcolor)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/725019921159028808/739770316754256012/Screenshot_20200803-1459592.png")
                .setImage(`${body.screenshot}`)
            message.channel.send(embed);
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to filter the NSFW url like

```
const link = ["pornhub.com","nhentai.net", and more...]
```

If someone send that link, bots sends an error/smth.

*sry, my English bad*

Comment: How does your program know what else is included in "and more..."?

Comment: more link, I shorten it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an exhaustive list of hostnames to block, you can check something like this:

```js
const blocked = ['pornhub.com', 'nhentai.net']

const Result = {
    Ok: 'Ok',
    Blocked: 'Blocked',
    Invalid: 'Invalid',
}

const checkUrl = urlStr => {
    try {
        const url = new URL(urlStr)

        return blocked.some(b => url.hostname === b)
            ? Result.Blocked
            : Result.Ok
    } catch {
        return Result.Invalid
    }    
}

for (const url of [
    'https://google.com',
    'https://pornhub.com',
    'https;//invalid.com',
]) {
    console.log({ url, result: checkUrl(url) })
}
```